# Complex data frame and transpose the data

Tags: r

I have a data frame as shown below:

```
ID  Capital  Instal  Date1 Date2
2    500      25      a     b
2    500      20      a     c
2    450      15      a     a
2    300      10      a     f
2    250       0      a     z
4    100      25      b     a
4    90       20      b     b
4    80       15      b     a
4    75       10      b     f
4    25        0      b     z
```

I want to create a new `data.frame` from this, where if `Date1=Date2` then my new data frame `B` would look like the one below:

```
ID  Date1  Capital  Instal1  Instal2  Instal3  Instal4
2     a     450       15       10       0
4     b      90       20       15       10       0
```

So I want the new `data.frame` to only consider the data after `Date1` and `Date2` are equal.

Comment: Subset on  `Date1 == Date2` then reshape from [long to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format).

Answer (score 2):

**tidyverse**

Here is a `tidyverse` approach (`dplyr` + `tidyr`):

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(cumsum(Date1 == Date2) >0) %>%
  transmute(Capital=Capital[1],Instal,Date1,colnames = paste0("Instal",seq(n()))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  spread(colnames,Instal)

df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0 # omit if you'd rather have NA
# # A tibble: 2 x 7
#      ID Capital Date1 Instal1 Instal2 Instal3 Instal4
# * <int>   <int> <chr>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1     2     450     a      15      10       0       0
# 2     4      90     b      20      15      10       0
```

The `filter` call removes rows before `Date1 == Date2`

With `transmute` we keep only necessary columns and create the column names that we will spread. We set all values of `Capital` to the first one as it's the only oe we need. `ID` is grouped so it's kept by default and is not allowed in `transmute`.

Then we `ungroup` and do a textbook `spread`

**base R**

In base R we can use `split` and `reshape` and follow the same ideas, with a bit of tedious reformatting in the end to pad the narrower sub data.frames.

```
df_list <- 
lapply(split(df,df$ID),function(x) {
  x <- subset(x,cumsum(Date1==Date2)>0)
  x <- transform(x, Capital=Capital[1], time = seq(nrow(x)))
  reshape(x,idvar=c("ID","Capital","Date1"),direction="wide",sep="",drop="Date2")
})
all_names <- names(df_list[[which.max(lengths(df_list))]])
df_list_full <- lapply(df_list,function(x) {x[setdiff(all_names,names(x))] <- NA;x})
do.call(rbind, df_list_full)

#   ID Capital Date1 Instal1 Instal2 Instal3 Instal4
# 2  2     450     a      15      10       0      NA
# 4  4      90     b      20      15      10       0
```

**data :**

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID  Capital  Instal  Date1 Date2
                2    500      25      a     b
                2    500      20      a     c
                2    450      15      a     a
                2    300      10      a     f
                2    250       0      a     z
                4    100      25      b     a
                4    90       20      b     b
                4    80       15      b     a
                4    75       10      b     f
                4    25        0      b     z",h=T,strin=F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` solution...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%   #group by ID
  mutate(ind=cumsum(Date1==Date2)) %>%  #mark elements after first Date1==Date2
  filter(ind!=0) %>%  #remove previous elements
  summarise(Date1=first(Date1),
            Capital=first(Capital),
            Instal=list(Instal)) %>%  #capture values for table
  unnest() %>%  #spread Instal, one value per row
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Inst=paste0("Instal",row_number())) %>%  #mark names of Instal values
  spread(key=Inst,value=Instal)  #spread into wide format

df2
     ID Date1 Capital Instal1 Instal2 Instal3 Instal4
1     2     a     450      15      10       0      NA
2     4     b      90      20      15      10       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the new data frame is coming out but the columns are not in order. How can I correct that.

Comment: You could simply use `transmute` instead of `summarize` then `unnest`

Comment: @N.Fungura They come out in the right order for me. `ID` will always be first, and the last four should be in numerical order. You can change the order of `Date1` and `Capital` in the `summarise` statement.

Answer (score 0):

A bit in a roundabout way. I'm sure there is a faster way of doing this, but this gets you exactly what you expect as output.

Steps: when date1 == date2 select the row_number and fill it out after the selection. Filter these records and select only the needed columns. create a column to be used as headers in the spread and spread the Instal data. next join a subset of the data to get the correct value of Capital and join this table with the previous selection.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(rowid = row_number(),
         selection = ifelse(Date1 == Date2, rowid, NA)) %>% 
  fill(selection) %>% # fill rowid over the rows after date1 == date2
  filter(!is.na(selection)) %>% 
  select(ID, Date1, Instal) %>% 
  mutate(Installation = paste0("Instal", row_number())) %>% 
  spread(Installation, Instal) %>% 
  inner_join(df %>% filter(Date1 == Date2) %>% select(ID, Date1, Capital), .)

  ID Date1 Capital Instal1 Instal2 Instal3 Instal4
1  2     a     450      15      10       0      NA
2  4     b      90      20      15      10       0
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    Capital = c(500L, 500L, 450L, 300L, 250L, 100L, 90L, 80L, 
    75L, 25L), Instal = c(25L, 20L, 15L, 10L, 0L, 25L, 20L, 15L, 
    10L, 0L), Date1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
    "b", "b"), Date2 = c("b", "c", "a", "f", "z", "a", "b", "a", 
    "f", "z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```